# Get an entity URL, not its path alias

Tags: entities, uri, 9

How can I get the URL of an entity without its alias?

This code just gives me the path alias, but what I actually want would be, for example, /en/node/1 instead of /en/node/my-title.

```php
$entity->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => true, language' => $entity->language()])
  ->toString(true)
  ->getGeneratedUrl());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the option `'alias' => TRUE` to your route. See how the shortlink is tested in core

```
  // \Drupal\Tests\node\Functional\NodeViewTest
  public function testLinkHeader() {
    $node = $this->drupalCreateNode();

    $expected = [
      '<' . Html::escape($node->toUrl('canonical')->setAbsolute()->toString()) . '>; rel="canonical"',
      '<' . Html::escape($node->toUrl('canonical', ['alias' => TRUE])->setAbsolute()->toString()) . '>; rel="shortlink"',
    ];

    $this->drupalGet($node->toUrl());

    $links = $this->getSession()->getResponseHeaders()['Link'];
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $links);
  }
```

Comment: Yes that works fine, thanks a lot :-)